# Image scaling disproportionally in Android default browser

Tags: php, android, wordpress, browser, image-scaling

I'm building a website on top of a Wordpress theme called 'Singular': [Singular demo here](http://wp.contempographicdesign.com/wp_singular/)

I noticed the logo image gets scaled disproportionally on Android's default browser, at least on my Galaxy SII with Jelly Bean 4.1. The image width seems correct, but height is too tall. The logo appears squashed. This doesn't seem to do with any of my modifications, but happens on the demo site too. I've mailed the theme provider about this, but deadline is closing in, so I'm trying to find out the solution on my own, too.

I wonder if this is a known Android bug, or something to do with the Singular theme specifically?

Nothing special seems to be going on in the original code:

```
<body<?php ct_body_id('top'); ?> <?php body_class(); ?>>

    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <?php if($ct_options['ct_text_logo'] == "Yes") { ?>
                <div id="logo" class="content-fade">
                    <h2><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h2>
                </div>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <?php if($ct_options['ct_logo']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img id="logo" class="content-fade" src="<?php echo $ct_options['ct_logo']; ?>" alt="<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>" /></a>
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><img id="logo" class="content-fade" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/singular-logo.png" alt="WP Singular, a WordPress theme by Contempo" /></a>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

I tried to hard code the correct height and width properties to the img tags, but it didn't solve the problem. I'm not sure what to try next. Any ideas?

---

Update: 
Thanks free3dom. Here's the end result of the styles applied to that img tag, according to Safari's Web Inspector:

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.6000000238418579s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: fadein;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-webkit-transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-width: 0px;
color: rgb(17, 158, 158);
cursor: auto;
display: block;
float: left;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
height: 20px;
line-height: 28px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
max-width: 100%;
opacity: 1;
outline-color: rgb(17, 158, 158);
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
top: 2px;
vertical-align: baseline;
width: 174px;
```

Well, width is defined, but height isn't. Doesn't Android browser calculate the correct height automatically? Although, hard-coding the width and height values earlier didn't seem to cure the problem anyways. I better re-check that to be completely sure.

Other than that, anything there that catches your eye? I couldn't find anything obviously responsible for the problem.

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: The image tag seems correct, but the CSS is most likely responsible for how it appears. Check what the CSS applies to `div`, `img`, `#logo`, and  `.content-fade`.

Comment: Thanks free3dom – I updated my question, but I'm still a bit confused. I tried hard-coding the proportions straight into the img tag, but, confirmed, it doesn't change the result. What I found out, though, adjusting the width has an effect, but adjusting the height does not. The height is automatically forced to fill whatever space there's left, no matter how you define it.

Comment: The CSS will usually override what you hardcode into the HTML. Try changing the `height: 20px;` value in the CSS (it is under `font-weight: normal;`). And also check the CSS for the containing `div`, as it may have a height that is too small and prevents the image from becoming larger (in height).

Comment: My explanation was a bit lacking, sorry. As the css style above is Safari's 'computed style', it provides both pre-defined styles and styles that are calculated on the go – the 'height: 20px' is simply a calculated result, deriving from these pre-defined width&height rows:
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}

I now tried adding:
img#logo.content-fade { 
 width:230px !important; 
 height:20px !important;
}
...to the stylesheet to be as precise as possible, but even though it works everywhere else, Android browser still stretches the logo.

Comment: Ah, I see. You could try using a `max-height:20px;` property. The only other thing that catches my eye is the `float` property, which is used to remove an element from the normal flow. I don't really understand why it would be used - though there could be any number of reasons, just not one I can determine from the given info. Other than that it could be related to the style of the `<div id="logo">` element, which is the container for the `img` tag. Try altering it's style to see if that makes any difference - ex. try making it larger and see if the image follows it's size.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Changing the size attributes have the desired effect on all other platforms I've tested, but with Android browser, only 'width' definition works – 'height' doesn't seem to affect the result at all; the image is automatically stretched to fill the vertical space available. (Oops, sorry, as you can see from the screen capture, the logo's *taller* than it should, not wider like I stated earlier.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35889/discussion-between-free3dom-and-samuli-viitasaari)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've been very busy over these couple of days – if you're still there, I'd be grateful about any tips in the chatroom.

Comment: Any word on this?  I'm running into the same problem.  On android, the default browser seems to ignore my height rules (no matter how many !important tags I place) and make the image extremely tall.  I haven't been able to find a solution to this.

Comment: Haven't been able to find a solution, @AndrewAllbright – and it's been very low on my priority list lately, so no help coming soon from here I'm afraid. If you do find a solution, though, I'd be glad to hear about it. Good luck!